# How to set global configuration in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am going to talking about some the config issue in Magento:

Let me assume that:

If I want to declare some global configuration in **`app/etc/config.xml`** for:

> I want to set delay time for refresh page as **5000ms**.

In the code, I will try to get like below:

```
Mage::app()->getConfig()->getDelayTime();
```

#### or

```
Mage::app()->getConfig()->get('delaytime');
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside `default` node put something like

```
<settings>
    <delaytime>5000</delaytime>
</settings>
```

and then get this value:

```
<?php Mage::getStoreConfig('settings/delaytime'); ?>
```