# MAgento - how to fix a constant in an xml file and get it in a template phtml file

Tags: magento

how can I fix a constant in an custom xml file and get it in my custom template phtml file ??

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Would this be what you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481287/how-to-set-global-configuration-in-magento

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481287/how-to-set-global-configuration-in-magento

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your config.xml

```
<default>
    <settings>
        <myconst>My Value</myconst>
    </settings>
</default>
```

In your .phtml file

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('settings/myconst'); ?>
```

Maybe this could help, I can't try the code at the moment.